# terraform-azure network interfaces error

Tags: azure, networking, terraform

I need some help regarding creating network interfaces azure terraform. I am getting an error while provisioning them. Please help me if i am doing anything wrong.

```
Error: 
azurerm_network_interface.revproxy-1: network.InterfacesClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="IpConfigDeleteNotSupported" Message="IP Configuration dataname-1-configuration cannot be deleted. Deletion and renaming of primary IP Configuration is not supported" Details=[]
* azurerm_network_interface.core-1: 1 error(s) occurred:
```

Comment: resource "azurerm_network_interface" "revproxy-1" {
  name                = "${var.rg_name}-interface"
  location              =  "${var.rg_region}"
  resource_group_name = "${var.rg_name}"
 ip_configuration {
    name                          = "revproxy-1-configuration"
    subnet_id                     = "${azurerm_subnet.reverse_proxy.id}"
    private_ip_address_allocation = "dynamic"
  }
}

Comment: Edit your question to include any additional relevant information instead of posting it in comments.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if we had additional information in the form of:

1. The full Terraform script used to deploy the infrastructure (not just the network interface part, since it depends on resources previously created but not present in the script provided in the comments).
2. The steps leading to this error.

It sounds like there was a multi-step process leading to this error. The error referencing ‘dataname-1-configuration’ but that name not being present in the script leads one to believe that the error is in the multi-step process. We could certainly be wrong, however, and the information above would help in understanding this.